# Change cookie attributes according to the request params

Tags: session, cookies, clojure, middleware, ring

I'm creating a proxy server with several middle-wares, one of them is ring 'wrap-session'.
I would like to be able to change dynamically the cookie attributes (max-age) that 'wrap-session' gets according to the request params.
this is the proxy creation:

```
(defn- make-server
  [port service-spec auth-app backend-bouncer]
  (let [backend (session-backend {})
        proxy-handler         (make-proxy-handler service-spec auth-app backend-bouncer)
        bam-auth-handler      (buddy.auth.middleware/wrap-authentication proxy-handler backend)
        wrap-session-handler  (wrap-session bam-auth-handler {:cookie-name "myCookie" :cookie-attrs {:max-age 3600}})]
    (jetty/run-jetty wrap-session-handler {:port (or port 3000)})))
```

how can I do it?

Comment: You have to write your own (modified) `wrap-session` for this. Copy and edit: https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/session.clj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was no other way but to rewrite `wrap-session` and another and to copy the private method `session-options` to my file and called it `local-session-option`, this is how I have done it:

```
(defn- local-session-options
  [options cookie-store]
  {:store        (options :store cookie-store)
   :cookie-name  (options :cookie-name "ring-session")
   :cookie-attrs (merge {:path "/"
                         :http-only true}
                        (options :cookie-attrs)
                        (if-let [root (options :root)]
                          {:path root}))})



(defn local-wrap-session
  [handler]
  (let [store (mem/memory-store)]
    (fn [request]
        (let [cookie-max_age (get-max-age request) ; add additional setting and calculation here
              options (local-session-options {:cookie-name "name" :cookie-attrs {:max-age cookie-max_age}} store)
              new-request (rms/session-request request options)]
          (-> (handler new-request)
              (rms/session-response new-request options))))))
```